# jquery sort not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working with one jquery for sort div using its row and column attribute.

See this fiddle

```
> See below fiddle link
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xyq9/9/)

This will work fine with Firefox and it will not work with chrome.

Can you please let me know what is the problem in this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got my answer.

```
$('#swappable > span').sort(function (a, b) {
  var ar = a.getAttribute("row");
  var ac = a.getAttribute("col");
  var br = b.getAttribute("row");
  var bc = b.getAttribute("col");

  if(ar > br)
  {
    return ar > br;
  }

  if(ar === br)
  {
    if(ac > bc)
    {
      return ac > bc;
    }
  }

}).appendTo('#swappable');
```

Please check below [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xyq9/22/)